# Why i can't load bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css

I' rocky and, after "Gettin started" I follow instructions of https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/
(I guess something is missing in that example)

I put:

- link to css file in head tag.
- near end of body, includes of jquery (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js)
- poperpopper.min.js
- and then bootstrap.min.js
  I have all the links and and all other includes finally I have:

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(sw) {  
    .hide-ph-flex {
        display: block; 
    }
} 

.hide-ph-flex {  
    display: none;
}
```

But it doesn't work, class "hide-ph-flex" its alway in `display: none`, and
FireFox debugger warns: `Unknown rule or error reading rule at @include`

I suppose I'm forgetting a file, 
ANY HELP???

Comment: That rule is from a SASS file. Are you compiling to CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Please, Note this line of your tutorial:

> Since we write our source CSS in `Sass`, all our media queries are available via `Sass` mixins

So, your imported code is `Sass` and you cannot import it on your project like `CSS`.

You can use these references for learning more about `Sass`:

- [Attaching a Sass/SCSS to HTML docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215517/attaching-a-sass-scss-to-html-docs)
- https://medium.com/@ricardozea/sass-for-beginners-the-friendliest-guide-about-how-to-install-use-sass-on-windows-22ff4a32c1f7
- https://sass-lang.com/guide

Answer (score 0):

@include is a Sass directive.  It will not work in a raw css file.  It has to be transpilied into a css file.

https://sass-lang.com/guide

Answer (score 0):

To add Bootstrap to your project, according to the instructions in the [*Introduction* page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/), you just need to copy-paste the following `<link>` into your `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```