# How to import SCSS files into HTML files

Tags: html, sass, scss-mixins

I create a simple website project with simple HTML and SCSS.

the HTML file seems like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello Bulma!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet/scss" type="text/css" href="./header.css">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="columns header-contents">
      <div class="column is-four-fifths">
        <div class="header-logo">
          hier ist logo
        </div>
        <div class="header-title"> Title</div>
        <div class="title-content">content</div>
      </div>

      <div class="column">Auto</div>
      <div class="column">Auto</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and I want to now import SCSS file into this HTML file, but it was not working.

Does anybody some solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attaching a Sass/SCSS to HTML docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215517/attaching-a-sass-scss-to-html-docs)

Answer (score 16):

If you use VSCode you can install "Live SASS Compiler"

[image: Live SASS Compiler]

Then you can create a .scss file and click on "Watch Sass" on bottom-right

[image: Watch SASS]

And it's going to compile your .scss file into a .css file that you can import into your HTML document.

Answer (score 5):

Browsers do not automatically understand the SCSS files, you need to compile such files first into CSS. If you are a `Node.js` user, you may install the SASS compiler by running the command:

```
npm install -g sass
```

Then compile your SCSS file by running the command:

```
sass input.scss output.css
```

Now you can link `output.css` in your HTML file.

Answer (score 2):

You don't import a SASS/SCSS file directly into an HTML file. Follow below steps

0. Type in terminal (if you have package.json in your project, you don't need this step) > `npm init`
1. Type in terminal> `npm i sass --save`
2. Add to package.json: `"scripts": {"sass": "sass --watch sass/style.scss:css/style.css",}`,
3. Add 2 folders (sass & css) and add a file in sass (style.scss)
4. Type in terminal > `npm run sass`

Answer (score 2):

Try using less:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="x.scss" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/less@4.1.1"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer to the question "how do I import **SCSS** files into my HTML page" is "Don't use SCSS, use Less"..?

Answer (score 1):

In codepen.io you can also work live with SCCS code. This is how:
In the CSS window pain, click on the little Settings icon on top right of the pane.
Then from the drop list for CSS Preprocessor choose SCCS.

I'm creating 3D text with it and it worked great. Now I have to compile that SCCS code to turn it into CSS. I will post it here after I figure out how to show you how cool it is or how badly things went.

This is my first time working with SCCS.

Comment: Browsers don't know SCSS, it is a different language closely resembling CSS and it has to be compiled to CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can only "import" css files. SCSS and co are preprocessors which take their custom syntax and transform it into CSS. So you have to convert your SCSS into CSS and then `<link>` it in your HTML like regular CSS (bc. thats what it is.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't import a SASS/SCSS file directly into an HTML file. Your SCSS will be compiled into a .css file, and you include that css file instead.

I would recommend looking up some tutorials on SCSS.

Answer (score 0):

you can't import directly scss file in html , because html just read css file and you need to comple sass file to css by gulp or webpack

Answer (score 0):

You can not "import" a SASS/SCSS file to an HTML document.
SASS/SCSS is a CSS preprocessor that runs on the server and compiles to CSS code that your browser understands.

Please use this link for compile sass/scss file.
https://thecoderain.blogspot.com/2019/12/run-and-compile-sass-scss-file-to-css.html

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio code, you can compile scss live. below are the steps

one time

```
npm i -g sass
```

To compile

```
sass --watch scss/index.scss css/index.css
```

In HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
```