# HTML & CSS animation not working when added to website

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a animation made in HTML & CSS on codepen.io, here's the animation - https://codepen.io/akshzyx/pen/OJOqpav.

It works fine on codepen but when tried to used in personal website, animations stop working.

Eyes blinking is the only thing that works on website. Tried in 2-3 browsers, same everywhere.

How can I fix this?

```css
// --- Variables --- //
$hover_top: 80px;
$hover_bottom: 30px;
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #2a88c5 url(http://zmwlt.com/bucket/cz-20150128-what-color-2-bg.jpg) center center / 70%;
  position: relative;
}

#robot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  max-width: 50vw;
  max-height: 80vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#body {
  animation: hover 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate
}

#head {
  animation: hover 1.1s ease-in-out 0.05s infinite alternate
}

#arms {
  animation: hover 1.1s ease-in-out 0.1s infinite alternate
}

#left_arm {
  transform-origin: center right;
  animation: arms_bounce_left 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate
}

#right_arm {
  transform-origin: center left;
  animation: arms_bounce_right 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate
}

#eyes ellipse {
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: eyes_blink 2s ease-out 0s infinite alternate
}

#shadow {
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: shadow 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate
}

// ---- Animations
@keyframes hover {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, $hover_top, 0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, $hover_bottom, 0)
  }
}

@keyframes shadow {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1.5, 1.2);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}

@keyframes arms_bounce_left {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, $hover_top, 0)rotate(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, $hover_bottom, 0)rotate(-10deg)
  }
}

@keyframes arms_bounce_right {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, $hover_top, 0)rotate(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, $hover_bottom, 0)rotate(10deg)
  }
}

@keyframes eyes_blink {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1)
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1, 1)
  }
  95% {
    transform: scale(0.8, 0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1)
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="robot" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 600 800" enable-background="new 0 0 600 800" xml:space="preserve">
  <ellipse id="shadow" opacity="0.4" fill="#2C3332" cx="300" cy="703.4" rx="89" ry="30.6"/>
  <g id="left_arm">
    <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M184 430.9c-44-18.9-84.8 18-94.2 44.1 -10.9-3.3-22.1-1.3-28.8 5.5 -1 1-1.8 2-2.6 3.2 -1.9 2.1-4.5 5.2-6.2 8.3 -5.8 10-2.3 23.1 7.7 32.4l3.8-3.7 5.7-7.1 -3.8 3.8c-6.8-6.4-10.6-14.6-10.5-22.3 -0.1 7.7 3.7 15.9 10.5 22.2l3.8-3.7c-4.8-5.1-6.7-11.7-4.8-17.3 5.6-3.5 13.8-3.4 21 0.8 8.7 5 13 14.3 10.5 21.7 -2.4 1.5-5.3 2.4-8.4 2.5l-5.7 7.1 0.1 6c8.5 0.8 16.5-1.6 21.7-6.8 1.2-1.2 6.3-7.3 7.2-8.8 0 0 0 0 0-0.1 0.6-0.8 1.1-1.5 1.6-2.4 5.5-9.5 2.6-22.1-6.4-31.2 13.2-12.9 33.1-25.2 48.8-9.1C156.5 477.4 189.1 433.1 184 430.9z"/>
    <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M106.3 485c-2.4-2.4-5.2-4.6-8.4-6.5 -2.6-1.5-5.3-2.7-8.1-3.5 -10.9-3.3-22.1-1.3-28.8 5.5 -1.2 1.2-2.3 2.6-3.2 4.1 -5.8 10-2.3 23.3 7.7 32.5l3.8-3.7c-4.8-5.1-6.7-11.7-4.8-17.3 0.3-0.8 0.6-1.6 1.1-2.4 4.1-7.1 14.2-9.2 23.3-5.1 0.8 0.3 1.5 0.7 2.3 1.2 1.9 1.1 3.6 2.4 5.1 3.9 5.9 5.9 7.9 14 4.3 20.2 -1.1 2-2.7 3.5-4.6 4.7 -2.4 1.5-5.3 2.4-8.4 2.5l0.1 6c9.4 0.9 18.2-2.1 23.3-8.7 0.6-0.8 1.1-1.5 1.6-2.4C118.1 506.6 115.2 494.1 106.3 485z"/>
  </g>
  <g id="right_arm">
    <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M547.7 492c-1.8-3-4.3-6.1-6.2-8.3 -0.8-1.2-1.6-2.2-2.6-3.2 -6.7-6.8-17.8-8.8-28.8-5.5 -9.3-26.1-50.2-63-94.1-44.1 -5.1 2.2 27.5 46.5 28.9 45 15.6-16.1 35.6-3.8 48.8 9.1 -8.9 9.1-11.9 21.6-6.4 31.2 0.5 0.8 1 1.6 1.6 2.4 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 0.9 1.6 6 7.6 7.2 8.8 5.2 5.3 13.2 7.7 21.7 6.8l0.1-6 -5.7-7.1c-3.1-0.1-6-1-8.4-2.5 -2.5-7.5 1.8-16.7 10.5-21.7 7.2-4.2 15.5-4.2 21-0.8 1.9 5.6-0.1 12.2-4.8 17.3l3.8 3.7c6.8-6.3 10.6-14.5 10.5-22.2 0.2 7.8-3.6 16-10.5 22.3l-3.8-3.7 5.7 7 3.8 3.8C550 515.1 553.5 502 547.7 492z"/>
    <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M547.7 492c-3.1-5.4-8.8-11-8.8-11s0 0 0 0c1.2 1 2.3 2.4 3.2 3.9 5.8 10 2.3 23.1-7.7 32.4l-3.8-3.7 5.7 7 3.8 3.8C550 515.1 553.5 502 547.7 492z"/>
    <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M489 518.6C489 518.6 489 518.6 489 518.6c0.9 1.6 6 7.7 7.2 8.9 5.2 5.3 13.2 7.7 21.7 6.8l0.1-6 -5.7-7.1 -0.1 6C502.9 528.2 494.1 525.1 489 518.6z"/>
    <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M534.4 493.8c-4.1-7.1-14.2-9.2-23.3-5.1 -0.8 0.3-1.5 0.7-2.3 1.2 -1.9 1.1-3.6 2.4-5.1 3.9 -5.9 5.9-7.9 14-4.3 20.2 1.1 2 2.7 3.5 4.6 4.7 -2.5-7.5 1.8-16.7 10.5-21.7 7.2-4.2 15.5-4.2 21-0.8C535.2 495.4 534.8 494.6 534.4 493.8z"/>
  </g>
  <g id="robot_main">
    <g id="body">
      <path id="SVGID_3_" fill="#BABEB7" d="M137.4 525.6c0-47.9 60.7-219.3 162.6-219.3 101.9 0 162.6 171.9 162.6 219.3 0 47.5-137.9 56.4-162.6 56.4C275.3 582.1 137.4 573.5 137.4 525.6z"/>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M200.8 522.8c0.1-0.4 0.3-0.8 0.4-1.2C201 522 200.9 522.4 200.8 522.8z"/>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M200.2 524.6c0.1-0.4 0.2-0.8 0.3-1.1C200.5 523.8 200.3 524.2 200.2 524.6z"/>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M201.3 521.1c0.2-0.6 0.4-1.1 0.7-1.6C201.8 520 201.6 520.6 201.3 521.1z"/>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M198.9 534.8c0-0.7 0-1.4 0-2C198.9 533.4 198.9 534.1 198.9 534.8z"/>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M199.8 526.4c0.1-0.4 0.2-0.8 0.3-1.2C200 525.6 199.9 526 199.8 526.4z"/>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M438.8 437.2c-21.1 18.1-64.2 43.3-140.1 43.3 -67.7 0-86.4 14.8-96.7 39.2 -1.9 4.5-3.1 9.7-3.1 15.1 0 13.9 7.7 29.5 29.4 40.2 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.3 0-0.5 0-0.8 0 0.3 0.1 0.5 0.3 0.8 0.4 31.4 5.2 61.4 6.7 71.7 6.7 24.7 0 162.6-8.9 162.6-56.4C462.6 508.1 454.3 473.7 438.8 437.2z"/>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M199 532.7c0-0.6 0.1-1.3 0.1-1.9C199.1 531.4 199 532.1 199 532.7z"/>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M199.2 530.3c0.1-0.5 0.1-1 0.2-1.4C199.3 529.4 199.2 529.9 199.2 530.3z"/>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M199.4 528.3c0.1-0.4 0.1-0.8 0.2-1.3C199.6 527.5 199.5 527.9 199.4 528.3z"/>
      <g id="percent_meter">
        <path fill="#EAECE8" d="M370.5 535.3c-0.1 0-0.2 0-0.4 0.1 -18 2.8-41.2 5-70 5 -44.7 0-75.9-5.2-95.4-10.1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0l-5.8 3c0 0 0 0 0 0 20 5.4 53.1 11.5 101.2 11.5 87.8 0 125-20 125-20l-4.5-3C420.7 521.8 405.2 529.8 370.5 535.3z"/>
        <path fill="#EAECE8" d="M175.2 524.9C175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9z"/>
        <path fill="#EAECE8" d="M175 524.8C175 524.8 175 524.8 175 524.8 175 524.8 175 524.8 175 524.8z"/>
        <polygon fill="#BABEB7" points="420.5 503.6 416.2 505.2 418.5 513.6 420.7 521.8 425.2 524.8 "/>
        <polygon fill="#8F918D" points="179.3 504 174.8 524.7 179.3 521.7 182.4 510.3 183.7 505.6 "/>
        <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M175 524.8c-0.2-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.2-0.1S174.9 524.7 175 524.8z"/>
        <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M175.2 524.9c1 0.5 3.9 1.9 9 3.8 6.6 2.5 14.6 4.5 14.7 4.6C184.8 529.4 177.1 525.8 175.2 524.9z"/>
        <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M175.2 524.9c-0.1 0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1C175.1 524.8 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9z"/>
        <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M175.2 524.9C175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9c1.9 0.9 9.5 4.5 23.7 8.4 0 0 0 0 0 0l5.8-3c0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.6-0.1-1.2-0.3-1.7-0.4 -16.2-4.2-23.7-8.1-23.7-8.1l-4.5 2.9c0 0 0.1 0 0.2 0.1 0 0 0 0 0 0C175.1 524.8 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9z"/>
        <path fill="#2b8fca" d="M368.7 521.5l-0.4-4.2c-18.5 3.2-41.7 5.8-68.2 5.8 -39.1 0-71.1-5.6-91.6-10.4 -0.5 1.7-0.9 3.2-1.3 4.6 -1.3 5-1.9 8.6-2.6 13 19.5 4.9 50.7 10.1 95.4 10.1 28.8 0 52-2.1 70-5L368.7 521.5z"/>
        <path fill="#2479b0" d="M203 511.3c-12.4-3.2-19.3-5.8-19.3-5.8l-1.3 4.7 -3.1 11.5c0 0 7.5 3.9 23.7 8.1 0.6 0.1 1.1 0.3 1.7 0.4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.6-4.4 1.3-8 2.6-13 0.4-1.4 0.8-2.9 1.3-4.6C206.6 512.2 204.8 511.8 203 511.3z"/>
        <path fill="#4C4C4C" d="M418.5 513.6l-2.3-8.4c0 0-17.5 6.8-47.1 12 -0.2 0-0.5 0.1-0.7 0.1l0.4 4.2 1.4 13.9c0.1 0 0.2 0 0.4-0.1 34.7-5.5 50.2-13.5 50.2-13.5L418.5 513.6z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="head">
      <path fill="#EAECE8" d="M460.3 268.3c-3-50.9-81.4-57.8-160.3-57.8 -78.8 0-156.6 6.9-160 57.4 -1.6 9.5-2.1 21.5-2.1 36.4 0 53.6 3.2 89.9 25.1 109.7 2 1.8 4.1 3.6 6.3 5.3 37.4 29.4 98.6 43.4 130.7 43.4 32.5 0 93.3-13.9 130.7-43.2 2.3-1.8 4.4-3.6 6.5-5.5 21.9-19.8 25.2-56.1 25.2-109.7C462.4 289.6 461.9 277.7 460.3 268.3z"/>
      <path fill="#9BB2B0" d="M444.4 302.4c-0.1-16.4-0.8-35.6-5.7-44 -1.3-2.3-3.6-6.2-19.4-7 -9.8-0.5-20.2-1-30.7-1.4 -33.2-1.3-67.8-1.9-88.7-1.9 -20.9 0-55.4 0.7-88.7 1.9 -10.5 0.4-20.8 0.9-30.5 1.4 -15.8 0.8-17.9 4.5-19.3 7 -4.7 8.2-5.5 26.8-5.6 43 0.1 46.6 1.8 76.4 17.2 90.4 2.3 2.1 4.9 4.2 7.5 6.2 33.3 24.9 89.7 38.8 119.4 38.8 25.6 0 71.6-10.3 105.3-29 5.1-2.9 10-5.9 14.4-9.1 3-2.2 5.9-4.5 8.5-6.8 6.3-5.7 10.2-14.1 12.6-25.2 2.9-13.5 3.5-31.1 3.7-52.7 0-3.1 0-6.2 0-9.4C444.4 303.7 444.4 303 444.4 302.4z"/>
      <path fill="#A4BCB9" d="M388.7 249.9c-33.2-1.3-67.8-1.9-88.7-1.9 -20.9 0-55.4 0.7-88.7 1.9 -28.7 17.5-46.9 49.3-46.9 104 0 14.9 7.8 27.4 19.9 37.7 32.3 27.6 94.9 39 115.8 39 17 0 61.7-7.6 95.1-25.3 7.6-4 14.6-8.6 20.6-13.7 12-10.3 19.9-22.7 19.9-37.7C435.6 299.2 417.4 267.5 388.7 249.9z"/>
      <path fill="#EAECE8" d="M428.2 391.7c-2.6 2.4-5.4 4.6-8.5 6.8 -4.4 3.2-9.3 6.3-14.4 9.1 -33.7 18.7-79.7 29-105.3 29 -29.7 0-86.1-14-119.4-38.8 -2.7-2-5.2-4-7.5-6.2 -15.4-14-17.1-43.8-17.2-90.4 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 50 3.1 81.8 19.2 96.4 0.9 0.8 1.7 1.5 2.6 2.3 32.3 27.2 91.1 41.7 122.3 41.7 28.6 0 80.5-12.2 113.8-35.1 3-2.1 5.8-4.2 8.5-6.4 1-0.8 1.9-1.6 2.9-2.5 7.9-7.2 12.7-18.6 15.6-34.2C438.3 377.5 434.5 385.9 428.2 391.7z"/>
      <g id="eyes">
        <ellipse fill="#2C3332" cx="231" cy="316.7" rx="6.3" ry="17"/>
        <ellipse fill="#2C3332" cx="369" cy="316.7" rx="6.3" ry="17"/>
      </g>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M460.3 268.3c-4-25.1-14.9-33.6-40-34.9 -41-2.2-92.3-3.3-120.3-3.3 -28 0-79.1 1.2-120.2 3.3 -25 1.3-35.8 9.8-39.8 34.5 -1.6 9.5-2.1 21.5-2.1 36.4 0 53.6 3.2 89.9 25.1 109.7 2 1.8 4.1 3.6 6.3 5.3 37.4 29.4 98.6 43.4 130.7 43.4 32.5 0 93.3-13.9 130.7-43.2 2.3-1.8 4.4-3.6 6.5-5.5 21.9-19.8 25.2-56.1 25.2-109.7C462.4 289.6 461.9 277.7 460.3 268.3zM444.4 313.7c-0.1 21.7-0.8 39.2-3.7 52.7 -2.8 15.6-7.6 27-15.6 34.2 -0.9 0.8-1.9 1.7-2.9 2.5 -2.7 2.2-5.5 4.4-8.5 6.4 -33.3 23-85.2 35.1-113.8 35.1 -31.2 0-90-14.5-122.3-41.7 -0.9-0.8-1.8-1.5-2.6-2.3 -16-14.6-19.2-46.4-19.2-96.4 0-1 0-2 0-3 0.1-16.2 0.9-34.8 5.6-43 1.4-2.5 3.5-6.2 19.3-7 9.7-0.5 20.1-1 30.5-1.4 33.2-1.3 67.8-1.9 88.7-1.9 20.9 0 55.5 0.7 88.7 1.9 10.5 0.4 20.9 0.9 30.7 1.4 15.8 0.8 18.1 4.7 19.4 7 4.8 8.4 5.6 27.6 5.7 44 0 0.7 0 1.3 0 1.9C444.4 307.5 444.4 310.6 444.4 313.7z"/>
      <g id="Robot_hat">
        <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M354.3 220.3c0-29.9-24.3-54.2-54.2-54.2 -29.9 0-54.2 24.3-54.2 54.2 0 4.7 24.3 4.7 54.2 4.7C330.1 225 354.3 225 354.3 220.3z"/>
        <circle fill="#F0C419" cx="300.4" cy="207" r="8.1"/>
        <circle fill="#E64C3C" cx="324.7" cy="206" r="8.1"/>
        <circle fill="#4EBA64" cx="275.3" cy="206" r="8.1"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: make sure it is *configured* as `scss`/`sass`,because that's how you coded in codepen

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **Complied CSS** to get the animations as you can't directly use the `SCSS` or `SASS` in your code as it is needed  to be compiled to `CSS` before using.

You can you some of online tools like [Json Formatter's SCSS to CSS tool](https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css) or any NPM packages like [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass), [scss-compile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scss-compile) etc.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #2a88c5 url(http://zmwlt.com/bucket/cz-20150128-what-color-2-bg.jpg) center center/70%;
  position: relative;
}

#robot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  max-width: 50vw;
  max-height: 80vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#body {
  -webkit-animation: hover 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
  animation: hover 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}

#head {
  -webkit-animation: hover 1.1s ease-in-out 0.05s infinite alternate;
  animation: hover 1.1s ease-in-out 0.05s infinite alternate;
}

#arms {
  -webkit-animation: hover 1.1s ease-in-out 0.1s infinite alternate;
  animation: hover 1.1s ease-in-out 0.1s infinite alternate;
}

#left_arm {
  transform-origin: center right;
  -webkit-animation: arms_bounce_left 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
  animation: arms_bounce_left 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}

#right_arm {
  transform-origin: center left;
  -webkit-animation: arms_bounce_right 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
  animation: arms_bounce_right 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}

#eyes ellipse {
  transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-animation: eyes_blink 2s ease-out 0s infinite alternate;
  animation: eyes_blink 2s ease-out 0s infinite alternate;
}

#shadow {
  transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-animation: shadow 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
  animation: shadow 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hover {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes hover {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes shadow {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1.5, 1.2);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}

@keyframes shadow {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1.5, 1.2);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes arms_bounce_left {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}

@keyframes arms_bounce_left {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes arms_bounce_right {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0) rotate(10deg);
  }
}

@keyframes arms_bounce_right {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0) rotate(10deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes eyes_blink {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  95% {
    transform: scale(0.8, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes eyes_blink {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  95% {
    transform: scale(0.8, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="robot" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 600 800" enable-background="new 0 0 600 800" xml:space="preserve">
  <ellipse id="shadow" opacity="0.4" fill="#2C3332" cx="300" cy="703.4" rx="89" ry="30.6" />
  <g id="left_arm">
    <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M184 430.9c-44-18.9-84.8 18-94.2 44.1 -10.9-3.3-22.1-1.3-28.8 5.5 -1 1-1.8 2-2.6 3.2 -1.9 2.1-4.5 5.2-6.2 8.3 -5.8 10-2.3 23.1 7.7 32.4l3.8-3.7 5.7-7.1 -3.8 3.8c-6.8-6.4-10.6-14.6-10.5-22.3 -0.1 7.7 3.7 15.9 10.5 22.2l3.8-3.7c-4.8-5.1-6.7-11.7-4.8-17.3 5.6-3.5 13.8-3.4 21 0.8 8.7 5 13 14.3 10.5 21.7 -2.4 1.5-5.3 2.4-8.4 2.5l-5.7 7.1 0.1 6c8.5 0.8 16.5-1.6 21.7-6.8 1.2-1.2 6.3-7.3 7.2-8.8 0 0 0 0 0-0.1 0.6-0.8 1.1-1.5 1.6-2.4 5.5-9.5 2.6-22.1-6.4-31.2 13.2-12.9 33.1-25.2 48.8-9.1C156.5 477.4 189.1 433.1 184 430.9z" />
    <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M106.3 485c-2.4-2.4-5.2-4.6-8.4-6.5 -2.6-1.5-5.3-2.7-8.1-3.5 -10.9-3.3-22.1-1.3-28.8 5.5 -1.2 1.2-2.3 2.6-3.2 4.1 -5.8 10-2.3 23.3 7.7 32.5l3.8-3.7c-4.8-5.1-6.7-11.7-4.8-17.3 0.3-0.8 0.6-1.6 1.1-2.4 4.1-7.1 14.2-9.2 23.3-5.1 0.8 0.3 1.5 0.7 2.3 1.2 1.9 1.1 3.6 2.4 5.1 3.9 5.9 5.9 7.9 14 4.3 20.2 -1.1 2-2.7 3.5-4.6 4.7 -2.4 1.5-5.3 2.4-8.4 2.5l0.1 6c9.4 0.9 18.2-2.1 23.3-8.7 0.6-0.8 1.1-1.5 1.6-2.4C118.1 506.6 115.2 494.1 106.3 485z" />
  </g>
  <g id="right_arm">
    <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M547.7 492c-1.8-3-4.3-6.1-6.2-8.3 -0.8-1.2-1.6-2.2-2.6-3.2 -6.7-6.8-17.8-8.8-28.8-5.5 -9.3-26.1-50.2-63-94.1-44.1 -5.1 2.2 27.5 46.5 28.9 45 15.6-16.1 35.6-3.8 48.8 9.1 -8.9 9.1-11.9 21.6-6.4 31.2 0.5 0.8 1 1.6 1.6 2.4 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 0.9 1.6 6 7.6 7.2 8.8 5.2 5.3 13.2 7.7 21.7 6.8l0.1-6 -5.7-7.1c-3.1-0.1-6-1-8.4-2.5 -2.5-7.5 1.8-16.7 10.5-21.7 7.2-4.2 15.5-4.2 21-0.8 1.9 5.6-0.1 12.2-4.8 17.3l3.8 3.7c6.8-6.3 10.6-14.5 10.5-22.2 0.2 7.8-3.6 16-10.5 22.3l-3.8-3.7 5.7 7 3.8 3.8C550 515.1 553.5 502 547.7 492z" />
    <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M547.7 492c-3.1-5.4-8.8-11-8.8-11s0 0 0 0c1.2 1 2.3 2.4 3.2 3.9 5.8 10 2.3 23.1-7.7 32.4l-3.8-3.7 5.7 7 3.8 3.8C550 515.1 553.5 502 547.7 492z" />
    <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M489 518.6C489 518.6 489 518.6 489 518.6c0.9 1.6 6 7.7 7.2 8.9 5.2 5.3 13.2 7.7 21.7 6.8l0.1-6 -5.7-7.1 -0.1 6C502.9 528.2 494.1 525.1 489 518.6z" />
    <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M534.4 493.8c-4.1-7.1-14.2-9.2-23.3-5.1 -0.8 0.3-1.5 0.7-2.3 1.2 -1.9 1.1-3.6 2.4-5.1 3.9 -5.9 5.9-7.9 14-4.3 20.2 1.1 2 2.7 3.5 4.6 4.7 -2.5-7.5 1.8-16.7 10.5-21.7 7.2-4.2 15.5-4.2 21-0.8C535.2 495.4 534.8 494.6 534.4 493.8z" />
  </g>
  <g id="robot_main">
    <g id="body">
      <path id="SVGID_3_" fill="#BABEB7" d="M137.4 525.6c0-47.9 60.7-219.3 162.6-219.3 101.9 0 162.6 171.9 162.6 219.3 0 47.5-137.9 56.4-162.6 56.4C275.3 582.1 137.4 573.5 137.4 525.6z" />
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M200.8 522.8c0.1-0.4 0.3-0.8 0.4-1.2C201 522 200.9 522.4 200.8 522.8z" />
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M200.2 524.6c0.1-0.4 0.2-0.8 0.3-1.1C200.5 523.8 200.3 524.2 200.2 524.6z" />
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M201.3 521.1c0.2-0.6 0.4-1.1 0.7-1.6C201.8 520 201.6 520.6 201.3 521.1z" />
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M198.9 534.8c0-0.7 0-1.4 0-2C198.9 533.4 198.9 534.1 198.9 534.8z" />
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M199.8 526.4c0.1-0.4 0.2-0.8 0.3-1.2C200 525.6 199.9 526 199.8 526.4z" />
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M438.8 437.2c-21.1 18.1-64.2 43.3-140.1 43.3 -67.7 0-86.4 14.8-96.7 39.2 -1.9 4.5-3.1 9.7-3.1 15.1 0 13.9 7.7 29.5 29.4 40.2 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.3 0-0.5 0-0.8 0 0.3 0.1 0.5 0.3 0.8 0.4 31.4 5.2 61.4 6.7 71.7 6.7 24.7 0 162.6-8.9 162.6-56.4C462.6 508.1 454.3 473.7 438.8 437.2z" />
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M199 532.7c0-0.6 0.1-1.3 0.1-1.9C199.1 531.4 199 532.1 199 532.7z" />
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M199.2 530.3c0.1-0.5 0.1-1 0.2-1.4C199.3 529.4 199.2 529.9 199.2 530.3z" />
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M199.4 528.3c0.1-0.4 0.1-0.8 0.2-1.3C199.6 527.5 199.5 527.9 199.4 528.3z" />
      <g id="percent_meter">
        <path fill="#EAECE8" d="M370.5 535.3c-0.1 0-0.2 0-0.4 0.1 -18 2.8-41.2 5-70 5 -44.7 0-75.9-5.2-95.4-10.1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0l-5.8 3c0 0 0 0 0 0 20 5.4 53.1 11.5 101.2 11.5 87.8 0 125-20 125-20l-4.5-3C420.7 521.8 405.2 529.8 370.5 535.3z" />
        <path fill="#EAECE8" d="M175.2 524.9C175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9z" />
        <path fill="#EAECE8" d="M175 524.8C175 524.8 175 524.8 175 524.8 175 524.8 175 524.8 175 524.8z" />
        <polygon fill="#BABEB7" points="420.5 503.6 416.2 505.2 418.5 513.6 420.7 521.8 425.2 524.8 " />
        <polygon fill="#8F918D" points="179.3 504 174.8 524.7 179.3 521.7 182.4 510.3 183.7 505.6 " />
        <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M175 524.8c-0.2-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.2-0.1S174.9 524.7 175 524.8z" />
        <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M175.2 524.9c1 0.5 3.9 1.9 9 3.8 6.6 2.5 14.6 4.5 14.7 4.6C184.8 529.4 177.1 525.8 175.2 524.9z" />
        <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M175.2 524.9c-0.1 0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1C175.1 524.8 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9z" />
        <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M175.2 524.9C175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9c1.9 0.9 9.5 4.5 23.7 8.4 0 0 0 0 0 0l5.8-3c0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.6-0.1-1.2-0.3-1.7-0.4 -16.2-4.2-23.7-8.1-23.7-8.1l-4.5 2.9c0 0 0.1 0 0.2 0.1 0 0 0 0 0 0C175.1 524.8 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9z" />
        <path fill="#2b8fca" d="M368.7 521.5l-0.4-4.2c-18.5 3.2-41.7 5.8-68.2 5.8 -39.1 0-71.1-5.6-91.6-10.4 -0.5 1.7-0.9 3.2-1.3 4.6 -1.3 5-1.9 8.6-2.6 13 19.5 4.9 50.7 10.1 95.4 10.1 28.8 0 52-2.1 70-5L368.7 521.5z" />
        <path fill="#2479b0" d="M203 511.3c-12.4-3.2-19.3-5.8-19.3-5.8l-1.3 4.7 -3.1 11.5c0 0 7.5 3.9 23.7 8.1 0.6 0.1 1.1 0.3 1.7 0.4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.6-4.4 1.3-8 2.6-13 0.4-1.4 0.8-2.9 1.3-4.6C206.6 512.2 204.8 511.8 203 511.3z" />
        <path fill="#4C4C4C" d="M418.5 513.6l-2.3-8.4c0 0-17.5 6.8-47.1 12 -0.2 0-0.5 0.1-0.7 0.1l0.4 4.2 1.4 13.9c0.1 0 0.2 0 0.4-0.1 34.7-5.5 50.2-13.5 50.2-13.5L418.5 513.6z" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="head">
      <path fill="#EAECE8" d="M460.3 268.3c-3-50.9-81.4-57.8-160.3-57.8 -78.8 0-156.6 6.9-160 57.4 -1.6 9.5-2.1 21.5-2.1 36.4 0 53.6 3.2 89.9 25.1 109.7 2 1.8 4.1 3.6 6.3 5.3 37.4 29.4 98.6 43.4 130.7 43.4 32.5 0 93.3-13.9 130.7-43.2 2.3-1.8 4.4-3.6 6.5-5.5 21.9-19.8 25.2-56.1 25.2-109.7C462.4 289.6 461.9 277.7 460.3 268.3z" />
      <path fill="#9BB2B0" d="M444.4 302.4c-0.1-16.4-0.8-35.6-5.7-44 -1.3-2.3-3.6-6.2-19.4-7 -9.8-0.5-20.2-1-30.7-1.4 -33.2-1.3-67.8-1.9-88.7-1.9 -20.9 0-55.4 0.7-88.7 1.9 -10.5 0.4-20.8 0.9-30.5 1.4 -15.8 0.8-17.9 4.5-19.3 7 -4.7 8.2-5.5 26.8-5.6 43 0.1 46.6 1.8 76.4 17.2 90.4 2.3 2.1 4.9 4.2 7.5 6.2 33.3 24.9 89.7 38.8 119.4 38.8 25.6 0 71.6-10.3 105.3-29 5.1-2.9 10-5.9 14.4-9.1 3-2.2 5.9-4.5 8.5-6.8 6.3-5.7 10.2-14.1 12.6-25.2 2.9-13.5 3.5-31.1 3.7-52.7 0-3.1 0-6.2 0-9.4C444.4 303.7 444.4 303 444.4 302.4z" />
      <path fill="#A4BCB9" d="M388.7 249.9c-33.2-1.3-67.8-1.9-88.7-1.9 -20.9 0-55.4 0.7-88.7 1.9 -28.7 17.5-46.9 49.3-46.9 104 0 14.9 7.8 27.4 19.9 37.7 32.3 27.6 94.9 39 115.8 39 17 0 61.7-7.6 95.1-25.3 7.6-4 14.6-8.6 20.6-13.7 12-10.3 19.9-22.7 19.9-37.7C435.6 299.2 417.4 267.5 388.7 249.9z" />
      <path fill="#EAECE8" d="M428.2 391.7c-2.6 2.4-5.4 4.6-8.5 6.8 -4.4 3.2-9.3 6.3-14.4 9.1 -33.7 18.7-79.7 29-105.3 29 -29.7 0-86.1-14-119.4-38.8 -2.7-2-5.2-4-7.5-6.2 -15.4-14-17.1-43.8-17.2-90.4 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 50 3.1 81.8 19.2 96.4 0.9 0.8 1.7 1.5 2.6 2.3 32.3 27.2 91.1 41.7 122.3 41.7 28.6 0 80.5-12.2 113.8-35.1 3-2.1 5.8-4.2 8.5-6.4 1-0.8 1.9-1.6 2.9-2.5 7.9-7.2 12.7-18.6 15.6-34.2C438.3 377.5 434.5 385.9 428.2 391.7z" />
      <g id="eyes">
        <ellipse fill="#2C3332" cx="231" cy="316.7" rx="6.3" ry="17" />
        <ellipse fill="#2C3332" cx="369" cy="316.7" rx="6.3" ry="17" />
      </g>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M460.3 268.3c-4-25.1-14.9-33.6-40-34.9 -41-2.2-92.3-3.3-120.3-3.3 -28 0-79.1 1.2-120.2 3.3 -25 1.3-35.8 9.8-39.8 34.5 -1.6 9.5-2.1 21.5-2.1 36.4 0 53.6 3.2 89.9 25.1 109.7 2 1.8 4.1 3.6 6.3 5.3 37.4 29.4 98.6 43.4 130.7 43.4 32.5 0 93.3-13.9 130.7-43.2 2.3-1.8 4.4-3.6 6.5-5.5 21.9-19.8 25.2-56.1 25.2-109.7C462.4 289.6 461.9 277.7 460.3 268.3zM444.4 313.7c-0.1 21.7-0.8 39.2-3.7 52.7 -2.8 15.6-7.6 27-15.6 34.2 -0.9 0.8-1.9 1.7-2.9 2.5 -2.7 2.2-5.5 4.4-8.5 6.4 -33.3 23-85.2 35.1-113.8 35.1 -31.2 0-90-14.5-122.3-41.7 -0.9-0.8-1.8-1.5-2.6-2.3 -16-14.6-19.2-46.4-19.2-96.4 0-1 0-2 0-3 0.1-16.2 0.9-34.8 5.6-43 1.4-2.5 3.5-6.2 19.3-7 9.7-0.5 20.1-1 30.5-1.4 33.2-1.3 67.8-1.9 88.7-1.9 20.9 0 55.5 0.7 88.7 1.9 10.5 0.4 20.9 0.9 30.7 1.4 15.8 0.8 18.1 4.7 19.4 7 4.8 8.4 5.6 27.6 5.7 44 0 0.7 0 1.3 0 1.9C444.4 307.5 444.4 310.6 444.4 313.7z" />
      <g id="Robot_hat">
        <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M354.3 220.3c0-29.9-24.3-54.2-54.2-54.2 -29.9 0-54.2 24.3-54.2 54.2 0 4.7 24.3 4.7 54.2 4.7C330.1 225 354.3 225 354.3 220.3z" />
        <circle fill="#F0C419" cx="300.4" cy="207" r="8.1" />
        <circle fill="#E64C3C" cx="324.7" cy="206" r="8.1" />
        <circle fill="#4EBA64" cx="275.3" cy="206" r="8.1" />
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**JsFiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/sh9wqay5/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### Export your code pen

### Extract the `zip`

### In the `/dist` directory

The `index.html` will **work**

The problem is you have to use `compiled CSS code`,and not the `scss`

> If you use VSCode you can install "Live SASS Compiler"

[see this other SO Question and its **answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60602125/14862885)

### RUN THE WORKING SNIPPET BELOW

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #2a88c5 url(http://zmwlt.com/bucket/cz-20150128-what-color-2-bg.jpg) center center/70%;
  position: relative;
}

#robot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  max-width: 50vw;
  max-height: 80vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#body {
  -webkit-animation: hover 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
          animation: hover 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}

#head {
  -webkit-animation: hover 1.1s ease-in-out 0.05s infinite alternate;
          animation: hover 1.1s ease-in-out 0.05s infinite alternate;
}

#arms {
  -webkit-animation: hover 1.1s ease-in-out 0.1s infinite alternate;
          animation: hover 1.1s ease-in-out 0.1s infinite alternate;
}

#left_arm {
  transform-origin: center right;
  -webkit-animation: arms_bounce_left 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
          animation: arms_bounce_left 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}

#right_arm {
  transform-origin: center left;
  -webkit-animation: arms_bounce_right 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
          animation: arms_bounce_right 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}

#eyes ellipse {
  transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-animation: eyes_blink 2s ease-out 0s infinite alternate;
          animation: eyes_blink 2s ease-out 0s infinite alternate;
}

#shadow {
  transform-origin: center center;
  -webkit-animation: shadow 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
          animation: shadow 1.1s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hover {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes hover {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes shadow {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1.5, 1.2);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}
@keyframes shadow {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1.5, 1.2);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes arms_bounce_left {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}
@keyframes arms_bounce_left {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0) rotate(-10deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes arms_bounce_right {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0) rotate(10deg);
  }
}
@keyframes arms_bounce_right {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 80px, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 30px, 0) rotate(10deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes eyes_blink {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  95% {
    transform: scale(0.8, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes eyes_blink {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  95% {
    transform: scale(0.8, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="robot" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 600 800" enable-background="new 0 0 600 800" xml:space="preserve">
  <ellipse id="shadow" opacity="0.4" fill="#2C3332" cx="300" cy="703.4" rx="89" ry="30.6"/>
  <g id="left_arm">
    <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M184 430.9c-44-18.9-84.8 18-94.2 44.1 -10.9-3.3-22.1-1.3-28.8 5.5 -1 1-1.8 2-2.6 3.2 -1.9 2.1-4.5 5.2-6.2 8.3 -5.8 10-2.3 23.1 7.7 32.4l3.8-3.7 5.7-7.1 -3.8 3.8c-6.8-6.4-10.6-14.6-10.5-22.3 -0.1 7.7 3.7 15.9 10.5 22.2l3.8-3.7c-4.8-5.1-6.7-11.7-4.8-17.3 5.6-3.5 13.8-3.4 21 0.8 8.7 5 13 14.3 10.5 21.7 -2.4 1.5-5.3 2.4-8.4 2.5l-5.7 7.1 0.1 6c8.5 0.8 16.5-1.6 21.7-6.8 1.2-1.2 6.3-7.3 7.2-8.8 0 0 0 0 0-0.1 0.6-0.8 1.1-1.5 1.6-2.4 5.5-9.5 2.6-22.1-6.4-31.2 13.2-12.9 33.1-25.2 48.8-9.1C156.5 477.4 189.1 433.1 184 430.9z"/>
    <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M106.3 485c-2.4-2.4-5.2-4.6-8.4-6.5 -2.6-1.5-5.3-2.7-8.1-3.5 -10.9-3.3-22.1-1.3-28.8 5.5 -1.2 1.2-2.3 2.6-3.2 4.1 -5.8 10-2.3 23.3 7.7 32.5l3.8-3.7c-4.8-5.1-6.7-11.7-4.8-17.3 0.3-0.8 0.6-1.6 1.1-2.4 4.1-7.1 14.2-9.2 23.3-5.1 0.8 0.3 1.5 0.7 2.3 1.2 1.9 1.1 3.6 2.4 5.1 3.9 5.9 5.9 7.9 14 4.3 20.2 -1.1 2-2.7 3.5-4.6 4.7 -2.4 1.5-5.3 2.4-8.4 2.5l0.1 6c9.4 0.9 18.2-2.1 23.3-8.7 0.6-0.8 1.1-1.5 1.6-2.4C118.1 506.6 115.2 494.1 106.3 485z"/>
  </g>
  <g id="right_arm">
    <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M547.7 492c-1.8-3-4.3-6.1-6.2-8.3 -0.8-1.2-1.6-2.2-2.6-3.2 -6.7-6.8-17.8-8.8-28.8-5.5 -9.3-26.1-50.2-63-94.1-44.1 -5.1 2.2 27.5 46.5 28.9 45 15.6-16.1 35.6-3.8 48.8 9.1 -8.9 9.1-11.9 21.6-6.4 31.2 0.5 0.8 1 1.6 1.6 2.4 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 0.9 1.6 6 7.6 7.2 8.8 5.2 5.3 13.2 7.7 21.7 6.8l0.1-6 -5.7-7.1c-3.1-0.1-6-1-8.4-2.5 -2.5-7.5 1.8-16.7 10.5-21.7 7.2-4.2 15.5-4.2 21-0.8 1.9 5.6-0.1 12.2-4.8 17.3l3.8 3.7c6.8-6.3 10.6-14.5 10.5-22.2 0.2 7.8-3.6 16-10.5 22.3l-3.8-3.7 5.7 7 3.8 3.8C550 515.1 553.5 502 547.7 492z"/>
    <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M547.7 492c-3.1-5.4-8.8-11-8.8-11s0 0 0 0c1.2 1 2.3 2.4 3.2 3.9 5.8 10 2.3 23.1-7.7 32.4l-3.8-3.7 5.7 7 3.8 3.8C550 515.1 553.5 502 547.7 492z"/>
    <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M489 518.6C489 518.6 489 518.6 489 518.6c0.9 1.6 6 7.7 7.2 8.9 5.2 5.3 13.2 7.7 21.7 6.8l0.1-6 -5.7-7.1 -0.1 6C502.9 528.2 494.1 525.1 489 518.6z"/>
    <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M534.4 493.8c-4.1-7.1-14.2-9.2-23.3-5.1 -0.8 0.3-1.5 0.7-2.3 1.2 -1.9 1.1-3.6 2.4-5.1 3.9 -5.9 5.9-7.9 14-4.3 20.2 1.1 2 2.7 3.5 4.6 4.7 -2.5-7.5 1.8-16.7 10.5-21.7 7.2-4.2 15.5-4.2 21-0.8C535.2 495.4 534.8 494.6 534.4 493.8z"/>
  </g>
  <g id="robot_main">
    <g id="body">
      <path id="SVGID_3_" fill="#BABEB7" d="M137.4 525.6c0-47.9 60.7-219.3 162.6-219.3 101.9 0 162.6 171.9 162.6 219.3 0 47.5-137.9 56.4-162.6 56.4C275.3 582.1 137.4 573.5 137.4 525.6z"/>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M200.8 522.8c0.1-0.4 0.3-0.8 0.4-1.2C201 522 200.9 522.4 200.8 522.8z"/>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M200.2 524.6c0.1-0.4 0.2-0.8 0.3-1.1C200.5 523.8 200.3 524.2 200.2 524.6z"/>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M201.3 521.1c0.2-0.6 0.4-1.1 0.7-1.6C201.8 520 201.6 520.6 201.3 521.1z"/>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M198.9 534.8c0-0.7 0-1.4 0-2C198.9 533.4 198.9 534.1 198.9 534.8z"/>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M199.8 526.4c0.1-0.4 0.2-0.8 0.3-1.2C200 525.6 199.9 526 199.8 526.4z"/>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M438.8 437.2c-21.1 18.1-64.2 43.3-140.1 43.3 -67.7 0-86.4 14.8-96.7 39.2 -1.9 4.5-3.1 9.7-3.1 15.1 0 13.9 7.7 29.5 29.4 40.2 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.3 0-0.5 0-0.8 0 0.3 0.1 0.5 0.3 0.8 0.4 31.4 5.2 61.4 6.7 71.7 6.7 24.7 0 162.6-8.9 162.6-56.4C462.6 508.1 454.3 473.7 438.8 437.2z"/>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M199 532.7c0-0.6 0.1-1.3 0.1-1.9C199.1 531.4 199 532.1 199 532.7z"/>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M199.2 530.3c0.1-0.5 0.1-1 0.2-1.4C199.3 529.4 199.2 529.9 199.2 530.3z"/>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M199.4 528.3c0.1-0.4 0.1-0.8 0.2-1.3C199.6 527.5 199.5 527.9 199.4 528.3z"/>
      <g id="percent_meter">
        <path fill="#EAECE8" d="M370.5 535.3c-0.1 0-0.2 0-0.4 0.1 -18 2.8-41.2 5-70 5 -44.7 0-75.9-5.2-95.4-10.1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0l-5.8 3c0 0 0 0 0 0 20 5.4 53.1 11.5 101.2 11.5 87.8 0 125-20 125-20l-4.5-3C420.7 521.8 405.2 529.8 370.5 535.3z"/>
        <path fill="#EAECE8" d="M175.2 524.9C175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9z"/>
        <path fill="#EAECE8" d="M175 524.8C175 524.8 175 524.8 175 524.8 175 524.8 175 524.8 175 524.8z"/>
        <polygon fill="#BABEB7" points="420.5 503.6 416.2 505.2 418.5 513.6 420.7 521.8 425.2 524.8 "/>
        <polygon fill="#8F918D" points="179.3 504 174.8 524.7 179.3 521.7 182.4 510.3 183.7 505.6 "/>
        <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M175 524.8c-0.2-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.2-0.1S174.9 524.7 175 524.8z"/>
        <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M175.2 524.9c1 0.5 3.9 1.9 9 3.8 6.6 2.5 14.6 4.5 14.7 4.6C184.8 529.4 177.1 525.8 175.2 524.9z"/>
        <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M175.2 524.9c-0.1 0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1C175.1 524.8 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9z"/>
        <path fill="#BABEB7" d="M175.2 524.9C175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9c1.9 0.9 9.5 4.5 23.7 8.4 0 0 0 0 0 0l5.8-3c0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.6-0.1-1.2-0.3-1.7-0.4 -16.2-4.2-23.7-8.1-23.7-8.1l-4.5 2.9c0 0 0.1 0 0.2 0.1 0 0 0 0 0 0C175.1 524.8 175.2 524.9 175.2 524.9z"/>
        <path fill="#2b8fca" d="M368.7 521.5l-0.4-4.2c-18.5 3.2-41.7 5.8-68.2 5.8 -39.1 0-71.1-5.6-91.6-10.4 -0.5 1.7-0.9 3.2-1.3 4.6 -1.3 5-1.9 8.6-2.6 13 19.5 4.9 50.7 10.1 95.4 10.1 28.8 0 52-2.1 70-5L368.7 521.5z"/>
        <path fill="#2479b0" d="M203 511.3c-12.4-3.2-19.3-5.8-19.3-5.8l-1.3 4.7 -3.1 11.5c0 0 7.5 3.9 23.7 8.1 0.6 0.1 1.1 0.3 1.7 0.4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.6-4.4 1.3-8 2.6-13 0.4-1.4 0.8-2.9 1.3-4.6C206.6 512.2 204.8 511.8 203 511.3z"/>
        <path fill="#4C4C4C" d="M418.5 513.6l-2.3-8.4c0 0-17.5 6.8-47.1 12 -0.2 0-0.5 0.1-0.7 0.1l0.4 4.2 1.4 13.9c0.1 0 0.2 0 0.4-0.1 34.7-5.5 50.2-13.5 50.2-13.5L418.5 513.6z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="head">
      <path fill="#EAECE8" d="M460.3 268.3c-3-50.9-81.4-57.8-160.3-57.8 -78.8 0-156.6 6.9-160 57.4 -1.6 9.5-2.1 21.5-2.1 36.4 0 53.6 3.2 89.9 25.1 109.7 2 1.8 4.1 3.6 6.3 5.3 37.4 29.4 98.6 43.4 130.7 43.4 32.5 0 93.3-13.9 130.7-43.2 2.3-1.8 4.4-3.6 6.5-5.5 21.9-19.8 25.2-56.1 25.2-109.7C462.4 289.6 461.9 277.7 460.3 268.3z"/>
      <path fill="#9BB2B0" d="M444.4 302.4c-0.1-16.4-0.8-35.6-5.7-44 -1.3-2.3-3.6-6.2-19.4-7 -9.8-0.5-20.2-1-30.7-1.4 -33.2-1.3-67.8-1.9-88.7-1.9 -20.9 0-55.4 0.7-88.7 1.9 -10.5 0.4-20.8 0.9-30.5 1.4 -15.8 0.8-17.9 4.5-19.3 7 -4.7 8.2-5.5 26.8-5.6 43 0.1 46.6 1.8 76.4 17.2 90.4 2.3 2.1 4.9 4.2 7.5 6.2 33.3 24.9 89.7 38.8 119.4 38.8 25.6 0 71.6-10.3 105.3-29 5.1-2.9 10-5.9 14.4-9.1 3-2.2 5.9-4.5 8.5-6.8 6.3-5.7 10.2-14.1 12.6-25.2 2.9-13.5 3.5-31.1 3.7-52.7 0-3.1 0-6.2 0-9.4C444.4 303.7 444.4 303 444.4 302.4z"/>
      <path fill="#A4BCB9" d="M388.7 249.9c-33.2-1.3-67.8-1.9-88.7-1.9 -20.9 0-55.4 0.7-88.7 1.9 -28.7 17.5-46.9 49.3-46.9 104 0 14.9 7.8 27.4 19.9 37.7 32.3 27.6 94.9 39 115.8 39 17 0 61.7-7.6 95.1-25.3 7.6-4 14.6-8.6 20.6-13.7 12-10.3 19.9-22.7 19.9-37.7C435.6 299.2 417.4 267.5 388.7 249.9z"/>
      <path fill="#EAECE8" d="M428.2 391.7c-2.6 2.4-5.4 4.6-8.5 6.8 -4.4 3.2-9.3 6.3-14.4 9.1 -33.7 18.7-79.7 29-105.3 29 -29.7 0-86.1-14-119.4-38.8 -2.7-2-5.2-4-7.5-6.2 -15.4-14-17.1-43.8-17.2-90.4 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 50 3.1 81.8 19.2 96.4 0.9 0.8 1.7 1.5 2.6 2.3 32.3 27.2 91.1 41.7 122.3 41.7 28.6 0 80.5-12.2 113.8-35.1 3-2.1 5.8-4.2 8.5-6.4 1-0.8 1.9-1.6 2.9-2.5 7.9-7.2 12.7-18.6 15.6-34.2C438.3 377.5 434.5 385.9 428.2 391.7z"/>
      <g id="eyes">
        <ellipse fill="#2C3332" cx="231" cy="316.7" rx="6.3" ry="17"/>
        <ellipse fill="#2C3332" cx="369" cy="316.7" rx="6.3" ry="17"/>
      </g>
      <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M460.3 268.3c-4-25.1-14.9-33.6-40-34.9 -41-2.2-92.3-3.3-120.3-3.3 -28 0-79.1 1.2-120.2 3.3 -25 1.3-35.8 9.8-39.8 34.5 -1.6 9.5-2.1 21.5-2.1 36.4 0 53.6 3.2 89.9 25.1 109.7 2 1.8 4.1 3.6 6.3 5.3 37.4 29.4 98.6 43.4 130.7 43.4 32.5 0 93.3-13.9 130.7-43.2 2.3-1.8 4.4-3.6 6.5-5.5 21.9-19.8 25.2-56.1 25.2-109.7C462.4 289.6 461.9 277.7 460.3 268.3zM444.4 313.7c-0.1 21.7-0.8 39.2-3.7 52.7 -2.8 15.6-7.6 27-15.6 34.2 -0.9 0.8-1.9 1.7-2.9 2.5 -2.7 2.2-5.5 4.4-8.5 6.4 -33.3 23-85.2 35.1-113.8 35.1 -31.2 0-90-14.5-122.3-41.7 -0.9-0.8-1.8-1.5-2.6-2.3 -16-14.6-19.2-46.4-19.2-96.4 0-1 0-2 0-3 0.1-16.2 0.9-34.8 5.6-43 1.4-2.5 3.5-6.2 19.3-7 9.7-0.5 20.1-1 30.5-1.4 33.2-1.3 67.8-1.9 88.7-1.9 20.9 0 55.5 0.7 88.7 1.9 10.5 0.4 20.9 0.9 30.7 1.4 15.8 0.8 18.1 4.7 19.4 7 4.8 8.4 5.6 27.6 5.7 44 0 0.7 0 1.3 0 1.9C444.4 307.5 444.4 310.6 444.4 313.7z"/>
      <g id="Robot_hat">
        <path fill="#DCE0DA" d="M354.3 220.3c0-29.9-24.3-54.2-54.2-54.2 -29.9 0-54.2 24.3-54.2 54.2 0 4.7 24.3 4.7 54.2 4.7C330.1 225 354.3 225 354.3 220.3z"/>
        <circle fill="#F0C419" cx="300.4" cy="207" r="8.1"/>
        <circle fill="#E64C3C" cx="324.7" cy="206" r="8.1"/>
        <circle fill="#4EBA64" cx="275.3" cy="206" r="8.1"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```