# why the sass codes don't apply to my html

Tags: css, sass, deployment, frontend

```css
p{
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sport.scss">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Helllooo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I wrote two other pages in this project correctly. But, when  intended to code the third one, changes didn't apply at all.it seems that my html code doesn't receive the styles.
Surprisingly, the sass file fully converted to CSS file, and no problem was evident.

Answer (score 0):

you must read documentation sass official and follow this guide https://sass-lang.com/guide. if you not install sass this two way how install sass

1. read this https://sass-lang.com/install
2. or download extension in visual code

if you are still confused change your sass become sport.css

Answer (score -1):

SASS / SCSS is a preprocessor for CSS, and can't be interpreted by your browser.
This is a duplicate question and possible solutions have alredy been described here: [Attaching a SCSS to HTML docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215517/attaching-a-scss-to-html-docs)

Answer (score -1):

if you are using vs code download a sass extension which will convert your sass code into a css code and then you can link that css file generated by the extension to your html page
i will recommend scss-to-css extension by yutent as it doesn't require you to make it active like other extensions